# Determine a polynomium $q \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ where the coordinat vector $[q]_v$ is equal to v where v is a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine a polynomium $q \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ where the coordinat vector $[q]_v$ is equal to v where v is a vector given by
$$
v = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \beta \\ -\alpha -\beta \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
My books has a note saying that the coordinat vector $[q]_v$ is given by the vector
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ ... \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} \in P_3(\mathbb{R})
$$
where 
$$
v = a_1 \cdot q_1 + a_2 \cdot q_2 + a_3 \cdot q_3
$$
where $Q = (q_1,q_2,q_3)$ is a basis given by $Q = (1,X,X^2)$. I am not really sure that I am explaining this correct so I have this is correct so far.

In regards I have then said that the polynomium q  will be
$$
q = \frac{1}{X^2} + \frac{-\alpha -\beta}{X} + \alpha \beta
$$
Is this correct? Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct. We have

$$q=\alpha \beta q_1-(\alpha + \beta)q_2+q_3,$$

hence

$$q(X)=\alpha \beta -(\alpha + \beta) X+X^2.$$